# Evolution operator of a two-level system in atomic clocks

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, unitarity, two-level-system, atomic-clocks

I have a few questions concerning equation (6) from this (http://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02537) paper from Weinberg in which he describes the time evolution of a two level system e.g. a Cs atom in an atomic clock with Lindblad formalism. Equation (6) should describe the evolution while the atoms are passing an external radiation field for a very brief moment, such that open system effects do not matter and to my understanding, this evolution should be unitary.

My three concerns are the following:

1. The evolution operator $U(t+\tau,t)$ as presented in equation (6) does not seem to be unitary. Using the basis $|g⟩⟨g| = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} |g⟩⟨e| = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, |g⟩⟨e| = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, |e⟩⟨e| = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$, I obtain

$U(t+\tau,t) = \pmatrix{\cos(Ωτ/2) & ie^{-iΔωt}\sin(Ωτ/2)\\-ie^{iΔωt}\sin(Ωτ/2)&\cos(Ωτ/2)}$

and with that

$U(t+\tau,t)U^\dagger (t+\tau,t) = U^2(t+τ,t) = \pmatrix{1 & 2 i e^{-iΔ ω t} \sin(Ωτ/2) \cos(Ωτ/2)\\-2 i e^{iΔ ω t} \sin(Ωτ/2) \cos(Ωτ/2) & 1}$

which is not the identity matrix. The evolution operator would be unitary if $U_{eg}(t+τ,t) = - U^*_{ge}(t+τ,t)$. Is there aby reason as to why this evolution should not be unitary?

2. The derivation of equation (6) towards the end of page 4. So my understanding is, he starts with the standard Lindblad equation (1) with the modified Hamiltonian $H\rightarrow H + H'e^{-iωt} + H'^\dagger e^{iωt}$ and then introduces a number of approximations. The first $\tau\ll|\lambda_{mn}|$ just manifests, that the non-unitary evolution part can be neglected, leaving only the unitary evolution part. The master equation is then the von-Neumann equation (in interaction picture):

$\dot{ρ}^I(t) = -i[H'e^{-iωt} + H'^\dagger e^{iωt},ρ^I(t)]$

The second and third "usual approximations" $τ|E_e - E_m|\gg 1$ and $τ|E_g-E_m|\gg 1$ just restate the fact that there are two relevant energy levels. The fourth one $τ|ω|\gg 1$ I don't understand (I am familiar with the rotation wave approximation in optical open systems, but don't see any links to that one). And then he states that "only those terms with time-dependence proportional to $\exp(\pm i Δ ω t)$" remain, which I would interpret as, the von-Neumann equation becomes

$\dot{ρ}^I(t) = -i[H'\exp(- i Δ ω t) + H'^\dagger \exp(\pm i Δ ω t),ρ^I(t)].$

I am not sure of the significance of the last approximation $|Δω| \ll |H'_{eg}|$, but it seems to assure that the off diagonals can be set $|H'_{eg}| = Ω/2$, so the driving Hamiltonian becomes

$H' = \pmatrix{0&Ω/2\\ Ω/2&0}$

I took that into the above stated von-Neumann equation and tried many different ways to obtain a differential equation, which yields the same time evolution, as if when applying the time evolution operator from equation (5), but never succeeded. So any help on how to derive the stated time evolution operator is greatly appriciated.

3. Then the last  thing is, if one takes the expression stated prior to equation (7): $ρ^I(t) = U(τ,0)ρ^I(0)U^\dagger(τ,0)$ and uses the time evolution operator stated in equation (6) and as initial state $ρ^I(0) = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$, then I don't get any exponential term in equation (7), as the time variable is set to $t=0$.

As this is a paper from Weinberg, I am first and foremost questioning my abilities to understand what he is doing, rather than questioning his work. So, if anybody could shed a light, where my thinking has gone wrong (or if Weinberg has actually done some minor mistakes in his expressions), I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix $U(t+\tau,t)$ should be of the  of the form
$$
\left(\matrix{a & -b^*\cr b &a^*}\right)
$$ with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ which is  unitary. You must have made a mistake when computing $U$ as you don't have the minus sign. Note that you seem to have said that $U=U^\dagger$, but that is not correct as for the unitary we have
$$
\left(\matrix{a & -b^*\cr b &a^*}\right)^\dagger = \left(\matrix{a^* & b^*\cr -b &a}\right).
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. That is exactly my point: I did not compute the matrix, but literary took it from Wineberg's paper. And it seems to not be unitary, so I was wondering if there is a reason, which I am not aware of, due to which it does not need tto be unitary or if Wineberg himself has done a mistake.

Comment: I think his eq 6 is just wrong. He intends $U$ to be unitary rather than hermitian.